# Carousel acting not sliding as it should

Tags: javascript, html, css, carousel, bootstrap-5

I Copied the bootstrap 5 Carousel code and made some additions to it but for some reason, it doesn't work (well it does but very weirdly) for example it goes only to the 2nd slide and then it stops but when I press f12, and go to inspect element it starts working. sometimes it doesn't even go to the 2nd slide.

This is my HTML code

```
    <!-- Image Carousel -->
    <div id=".Carousel" class="carousel pt-5 slide bg-dark" data-bs-touch="false" data-bs-ride="carousel">
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="carousel-item active" data-bs-interval="5000">
                <div class="ratio ratio-21x9"><img src="../FrontEnd/Images/Home/MainPicture.jpeg" class="ratio pt-3 ratio-16x9 d-block w-100"alt="Main Picture">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item" data-bs-interval="5000">
                <div class="ratio ratio-21x9"><img src="../FrontEnd/Images/Home/BiliardBar.jpeg"class="ratio pt-3 ratio-16x9 d-block w-100" alt="Billiard And Bar">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item" data-bs-interval="5000">
                <div class="ratio ratio-21x9"><img src="../FrontEnd/Images/Home/Darts.jpeg"class="ratio pt-3 ratio-16x9 d-block w-100" alt="Darts">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- End of Image Carousel -->
```

Lastly i want to mention my css file, i have dont have anything that could potentionaly harm the way my carousel works. BUT i have a nav bar over the top of my carousel with `Z-Index: 2;` (Carousel has 1) , but i tried removing it and my carousel was still bugged.

I tried googling some answers but nothing seemed to work I found some code stated that this:

```
<script>$(window).load(function () { $('.Carousel').carousel() })</script>
```

Should make the flashing animation between Carousel item swapping go away, but I have no idea if I used it right since i never worked with javascript (I have this at top of my page)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you to use this snippet for the carousel

```html
<div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img src="..." class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="..." class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="..." class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
    </div>
  </div>
  <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleControls" data-bs-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
  </button>
  <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleControls" data-bs-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
  </button>
</div>
```

And don't forget to fill the `src` attribute of your images